# Background task in web service application and stop it on web service calls. Java EE

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, scheduled-tasks, background-process, jaws-screen-reader

I have a JAWS Soap web service implemented in a J2EE web Application. This web service interacts with the Bluetooth devices.

I want to have a background running task always and when a request to the web service is made the background process have to be stopped because if the background task is running the Bluetooth device is not available.

I have seen the @Schedule annotation but I need to access the background task from the web service to stop it and then do the web service process.

When the web service process end the background task have to be started (may be if some minutes have been passes since the last web service call).

How can achieve this?

Comment: What is your platform? Java EE 7?

Comment: @SteveC Yes, I'm using Java EE 7. Do you have any idea about how to do that? Thanks